# Changing HTTP Headers

Tags: php, html, wordpress, http-headers, html5-audio

I'm having an issue with `HTML5 audio track duration` in **Chrome** and **Safari** browsers. (mobile too) **Firefox** is fine.

Instead of showing the track duration, it's showing "Infinity:Nan:Nan" in it's place.
[image: Odd issue with track duration shown here]

I am using a [jquery plugin](http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/) that automatically creates a fallback flash file of the tracks which are standard HTML5 `<audio>` tags:

```
<audio controls preload="none" itemprop="audio">
<source src="http://my-site/path/to/tracks/mus/Town_Where_I_Live_Prev.mp3" />
</audio>
```

The music player plays the tracks fine, it just won't show the duration number correctly.

I was wondering if it has to do with HTTP headers? I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/jplayer/JW0p_MFY-Ow) which I'm hoping will fix my issue, but I think I'm doing it wrong. He mentions that he had to change the Content Type to `"application/octet-stream"` and it fixed the problem for him. When I check the site's Headers I only see `"text/html; charset=UTF-8"`. I don't even see anything about `"audio/mpeg"`, but again the tracks play fine though even without that. So my question is do you think that might be a fix for me, and if so how do I go about adding/editing my site's HTTP header?

I have built this site with a custom wordpres theme, so I tried adding the following to my functions.php file to change the Header:

```
add_action( 'send_headers', 'add_header_vary_useragent' );
function add_header_vary_useragent() {
    header( 'Vary: User-Agent' );
}
```

And instead of `Vary: User-Agent`

I changed it to `'Content-type: application/octet-stream'`

And after doing that, if I visit the site, the browser actually automatically downloads the index file. **Safari** won't even open it, so I'm pretty sure that was wrong.

I also found [this over at the Wordpress area](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20192/wp-function-filter-for-modifying-http-headers) on modifying it, but I'm just unclear as to what I should be doing with it. I know my site is built on wordpress, but I am thinking this doesn't have to be WP related, so I posted here instead.

Any direction or suggestions is extremely appreciated!